# Java unit testing: the easiest way to test if a callback is invoked

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

I often work with methods that accept callbacks, and callbacks seem to be somewhat hard to test. Let's consider the following scenario, if there's a method that accepts a callback with a single method (for simplicity, I assume the testing method is synchronous), the following boilerplate could be written just to ensure that a callback method is invoked:

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
    final boolean[] passed = {false};
    method(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void handle(boolean isSuccessful) {
            passed[0] = isSuccessful;
        }
    });
    assertTrue(passed[0]);
}
```

It looks like a surrogate. I would like to know: is there a more elegant way to test such code to make the code above look more like the pseudo-code below?

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
    // nothing explicit here, implicit boolean state provided by a test-runner
    method(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void handle(boolean isSuccessful) {
            if ( isSuccessful ) {
                pass(); // not sure how it should look like:
                        // * an inherited method that sets the state to "true"
                        // * or an object with the pass method
                        // * whatever
                        // but doesn't exit testMethod(), just sets the state
            }
        }
    });
    // nothing explicit here too:
    // test runner might check if the state is changed to true
    // otherwise an AssertionError might be thrown at the end of the method implicitly
}
```

A little cleaner. Is it possible in JUnit, TestNG or any other testing framework? Thanks!

---

UPDATE

Sorry, I seem to have asked a vague question that doesn't really meets what I wanted to ask. I basically meant any code (not necessarily a callback) that might be invoked if certain conditions are satisfied just to *set the result state to true*. Simply speaking, I just want to get rid of the initial `boolean[] passed` and the final `assertTrue(passed[0])` assuming that they are some kind of prologue and epilogue respectively and assuming that the initial state is set to `false` so the `pass()` should be invoked to set the state to `true`. No matter *how* the `passed[0]` is set to `true`, no matter where from. But unfortunately I have asked this question using the context of callbacks, however this is just an option, not a requirement. Thus the title of the question does not reflect what I really wanted to ask, but before the update some answers have been posted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is typically what a mocking framework can do for you.

With [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) for instance:

```
// imports ommited for brevity
@Test
public void callbackIsCalled()
{
    final CallBack callBack = mock(CallBack.class);
    method(callBack);

    verify(callBack, only()).handle(any());
}
```

Of course, this is an example of verification mode (`only()`) and value matcher (`any()`). You can do more...

(other mocking frameworks exist, but I personally find Mockito the easiest to use, in addition to being one of the most powerful)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, Mockito is a really nice lib. To be honest, I didn't take the mocking libraries into account: I just wanted to get rid of the surrogate flag and the trailing asserts. With Mockito, `verify` must be properly invoked too. I just thought that the last assert might be implicit and "supplied" by the test runner.

Comment: Well, as I said, it is only a value matcher; if you want, you can replace the argument by `true`, or even an `ArgumentCaptor<Boolean>`.

Answer (score 10):

Given that this is the sort of thing you're likely to need in several places, I would just create a named class to use for tests:

```
public class FakeCallback implements Callback {
    private boolean wasSuccessful;
    private boolean handleCalled;

    @Override public void handle(boolean isSuccessful) {
        this.wasSuccessful = isSuccessful;
        handleCalled = true;
    }

    // Getters for fields above
}
```

You can then use something like:

```
// Arrange...
FakeCallback callback = new FakeCallback();

// Act...
method(callback);

// Assert
assertTrue(callback.wasHandleCalled());
assertTrue(callback.wasSuccessful());
```

You could absolutely use a mocking framework for this instead, but personally I find that often it's simpler to create a single fake implementation than set up mocks repeatedly. Both ways will work though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm also thinking of idea of getting rid of the trailing asserts (this is a part of probably vague question too), but I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv: Well what are you trying to test? If you don't care whether the callback was called or not, or what the argument was, then you can stub it out really easily...

Answer (score 2):

## Give list::add as callback

When the task is to test a callback that is a functional interface accepting one parameter (here a boolean, could as well be String or any random type), it seems most concise to prepare a list, pass the `List.add(e)` method as callback and then check the content of the list:

```
List<Boolean> callbackArgs = new ArrayList<>();
methodUnderTest(callbackArgs::add);
// assert that the callback was called exactly once and with a "true" value: 
assertEquals(Arrays.asList(true), callbackArgs);
```

Alternative case for a callback that accepts Strings:

```
List<String> callbackArgs = new ArrayList<>();
methodUnderTest(callbackArgs::add);
// assert that the callback was called twice with "foo" and "bar" values respectively: 
assertEquals(Arrays.asList("foo", "bar"), callbackArgs);
```

Analogously, a counter class may serve for testing a callback that accepts no parameter. Here using AtomicInteger, as that seems to be the only counter-like class available in the standard libs - the atomicity property is not needed here:

```
AtomicInteger callbackCounter = new AtomicInteger();
methodUnderTest(callbackCounter::incrementAndGet);
// assert that the callback was called 5 times: 
assertEquals(5, callbackCounter.get());
```

Comment: Just the heading made me realise how easy it is to test callbacks with this. I have a class that accepts a Consumer<MyObject> parameter. Simply passing in list::add as the consumer made the testing a whole lot easier as now I can just verify that the size of the list is what I expected, rather than making some strange things with mocks. So +1.